# integrating wso2 identity server and api manager

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I want to integrate WSO2 Identity server and API manager together so that user authentication can be done by WSO2 Identity server and API level authorization can be done in the API Manager.I am using WSO2 identity server separately so that one day if i have to remove API Manager , authentication will work properly.
Can someone explain the workflow/architecture? Where should i keep the users , in the identity server or in the API Manager?  I Would like to have the /oauth2/token token generation code to hit the Identity server .How can i achieve this?
Is there a cloud hosting for WSo2 Identity server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to configure WSO2 IS as an keymanager all the detailed steps can be found in WSO2 doc https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+the+Identity+Server+5.2.0+as+a+Key+Manager+with+API+Manager+2.0.0

Comment: can you explain a little bit workflow? 
Which all urls to access as oauth2 check points? Where should i add users , where should i add api's?
Will be grateful if you can throw some more information!

Comment: I think in this documentation it is clear  clearly mention the flow. If you are configuring your Identity Server as per this documentation with API Manager, you keep a shared database with API Manager and IS (Key Manager) where you store your users in a JDBC user store. By observing the [diagram in the doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+the+Identity+Server+5.2.0+as+a+Key+Manager+with+API+Manager+2.0.0) you can see how databases are shared. AuthManager and KeyValidator Server URL Mappings are clearly indicated in the documentation pointed.

Comment: Is there another architectural concept besides sharing the databases to integrate these products? I mean IS is able to perfectly act as IdP - is there any possibility to integrate it with this feature?

Comment: I didn't actually realize these were separate products until I came across this - thanks for the link!!